# phpfox how to change default users privacy

Tags: phpfox

I'm using phpfox version 4.3.1. I want to set profile for `anyone` privacy to all new users. I tried User `Default Privacy Setting` on Registration but does not work! No one is able to make their `profile publicly available`. I've spent many hours to look onto setting and google but found no solution yet. Please let me know Here is my site link:

[http://www.sindbah.com/user/privacy/ ]

Any Idea??

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Default Phpfox site is "Friends Only Community" so every profile is private from visitor and Not Friend of the user.

In your case do following thing:

- Search "Friends Only Community" setting on AdminCP
- Change it to "NO".

Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12417014)

Comment: I have edit the post to make it more clearly. Thanks for feedback